# Multiple Deck vs Single Deck Poker Game Calculation

Tags: probability, poker

I was reviewing some calculations for a $4$-card poker type table game and got confused about single vs multiple deck approach to calculating probability.  If someone could enlighten me, I would appreciated it.

Lets assume a single deck game, where there is a dealer and a single player, $2$ cards are dealt to each.  To compute the probability of having a combined exactly $3$-of-a-kind hand...my approach was as follows:

Denominator of picking any $4$ cards =$\binom {52}4$
interpreted as:  choose 4 cards from a single standard deck

Numerator of getting $3$ of a kind exactly:   $\binom{13}1 \times \binom43 \times \binom{12}1\times\binom 41$  interpreted as:   choose any value for the trips $\times$ choose  $3$ out of $4$ possible suits for this value $\times$ choose your unmatched value for the remaining card $\times$ choose the suit for this unmatched value.

Do the odds change in a multiple deck situation and can someone explain the math for such?   thanks

Comment: actually..it just occurred to me...i think i should not use the term 'suits'  but rather 'possible cards'   and in such case... ,  if it were 6 decks..  it would be denominator of 312C4    and numerator of  13C1  x  24C3  X 12C1 X 24C1

Comment: Maybe it helps to look at the "infinite" case (or, equivalently, the case where you draw with replacement).  In that case to get the pattern $AAAB$ exactly,  the first card can be anything, second card must match the first (prob. $\frac 1{13}$), third card also matches (prob. $\frac 1{13}$) and the fourth card doesn't match (prob. $\frac {12}{13}$)  multiplying we get $0.005461994$.  multiplying by $4$ (for the four possible patterns) we get $0.021847975$, as opposed to what you get for the ordinary deck:  $0.009219688$.  Makes a big difference!